# Linker script - map non-continuous memory

Tags: gcc, ld, linker-scripts

I would like to allocate RAM memory this way on my MCU:

[image: memory_map]

My physical ram is split into two parts and I can't allocate memory that straddles this boundary (physical constraint due to the component). Because of this constraint, I have to split my heap into two parts in my example.

Here is my linker script:

```
MEMORY
{
  RAM (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x00, LENGTH = (0x200)
}

SECTION
{
  .heap1 (NOLOAD):
  {
    _heap1_size = 0x80;
    . = . + _heap1_size;
    _eheap1 = .;
  } > RAM

  .unallocated_ram1 (NOLOAD):
  {
    _unallocated_ram1 = (0x100 - ABSOLUTE(_eheap1)); /* create an offset for .heap2 */
    . = . + _unallocated_ram1;
  }

  .heap2 (NOLOAD):
  {
    _heap2_size = 0x90;
    . = . + _heap2_size;
  } > RAM
}
```

At the end I would like the linker script to calculate the free available ram.
I use `--print-memory-usage` for linker to print the result.

In my case I would like the output to be:

```
free_ram = total ram - (_heap1_size + _heap2_size)
free_ram =    0x200  - (   0x80     +     0x90  )
free_ram =    0xF0 (240)
```

But as the `unallocated_ram1` part is in the RAM section, linker script will add it into ram size and prints:

```
free_ram = total ram - (_heap1_size + unallocated_ram1 + _heap2_size)
free_ram =   0x200   - (   0x80     +        0x20      +     0x90   )
free_ram = 0xD0 (208)
```

I know a solution is to put heap2 at a specific address with `AT` command but I don't want to as there is a risk of memory overlap (in my project there are many sections).

I also figured out that replacing `.unallocated_ram1` with a simple:

```
...
.heap1 (NOLOAD):
  {
[...]
  } > RAM

  . = . + _unallocated_ram1;

  .heap2 (NOLOAD):
  {
[...]
  } > RAM
...
```

Does not work as expected. It does not move the memory pointer.

**My question:** how to add a memory block that will not be counted against the RAM SECTION. In other words, how to put `.heap2` at an offset after `_eheap1`. How to map non-continuous memory.

Thanks for your help!